# Format type=text button with CSS

Tags: php, html, css, button, file-upload

I'm using a modified input button for users to upload a file.

I found this fiddle and used the same exact code and successfully generated a working CSS button.
http://jsfiddle.net/geniuscarrier/ccsGK/

```
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Uploads</span>
    <input type="file" class="upload" />
</div>

.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

The only problem is that once I use the button to upload a file, the message that typically shows up to the right of the button naming the file that has been selected is gone.

Therefore, it's impossible for the user to tell if the file has been selected.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use js/jQuery to read uploaded file name and place it as text inside `<span></span>` (or in any other place).

```
$('.upload').change(function(){
    $('.fileUpload > span').text($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but can you please be a little more specific as to how to do this?  I put your code in <script> tags inside the span, but it didn't work, but I'm guessing I'm missing something.

Comment: @Kevin to run his script you need to include jquery library

Comment: @Kevin yes, you are missing included jQuery and `$(document).ready(function(){/* my code */})`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `opacity: 0` on your `.fileUpload input.upload` css rule. Change it to something like 5 and you will see original file control coming up. However using file upload control in such way usually requires a   label/span that should be populated with the file selected. Name of the file selected, you can get from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what your requirements are but it appears that you are trying to style the file input button.

If you don't have requirements that you need to support old browsers, you can use -webkit-file-upload-button and -ms-browse properties to target the specific buttons. This would work only in IE10 and above and in modern webkit browsers. I modified the following based on your css so it should work:

```
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input.upload::-webkit-file-upload-button{
  visibility: hidden;
}

input.upload::-ms-browse{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

This will allow you to hide just the button part and you can place the button on top of your existing customized button. You can also target the input field directly once the button is hidden. For eg.

```
input.upload::before{
    content: 'Uploads';
    background:#00f;
    color:#fff;
}
```